# Raspberry Pi 4 configuration for use with battery

Tags: pi-4, battery

I need to use Raspberry with a battery pack the problem is that in normal configuration Raspberry expect a very stable and costant power supply and even a small change will cause a lot of warnings in the log and if it is attached to a battery it is near impossible to grant the same specs and there is fluctuation according the battery charge level.

How it should be configured to avoid these problems?

Answer (score 0):

Use a "better" battery.  I have no problem powering Pi's from batteries.

If you don't buy a battery of sufficient voltage and capacity no amount of configuration settings will help.

Comment: It's not a problem of good battery. Batteries have a voltage fluctuation according the charge level (and this is what allows to measure the battery percentage of charge). So regardless how good is your battery a configuration to properly address this would be useful.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming everything is sized to support your load and run time I would use a SEPIC converter that will supply at least 3A. The SEPIC converter will boost  or buck the voltage. This depending on where the battery voltage is in relation to the set point (output voltage setting). The reason the Pi does not have a regulator on board hence it has a tight voltage range it will operate in. I believe most if not all Raspberry models run on 5.1V power Caution with the Raspberries, the Pi 4 and 400 require 3A while other models can work fine on 2.5A. Using a phone charger or USB to power a Raspberry Pi is wouldn’t be recommended. This should get you going and be sure your batteries will supply about 30 watts or more. Voltage can range from about 2V to 30V depending on the SEPIC converter input requirements. This will allow you to charge the battery without removing it from the system or overvoltage the Pi. A relative SLA battery and an inexpensive charger sould work just fine.